# Microwave "power" vs "power consumption"

Tags: voltage, power, amperage, power-consumption, outlet

I'm looking at the specs for [this microwave](https://www.panasonic.com/ca/consumer/home-appliances/microwave-ovens/over-the-range/nn-sd291s.specs.html) and it lists `Power -> Microwave` as `1,100 W`, but then lower down it lists `Power Consumption -> Microwave` as `1,440 W`. Does anyone know the difference? The reason I want to know is that I'm trying to estimate the current when plugging this into a 120V outlet, so I want to know if it's 1100/120 or 1440/120.

Answer (score 4):

The 1440 W power consumption is what you can expect to supply from the 120V outlet. That supplies 1100 watts to cook the food and 340 watts of losses inside the microwave including power for the turntable motor, the controls, the heat produced by the transformer, microwave generator and associated circuitry and the motor that drives the fan to push the heat out into the room.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much everything has an inefficiency.  To produce 1100 watts of microwave power, your appliance requires 1440 watts in.

In terms of a steady state average, that is the power you would design for.

But when sizing sources or distribution, you have to overdesign.  And many times you must design to the circuit breaker rating, which will need to be above the load rating.   If you were thinking about something like an inverter power source you would have other factors to consider too.

So you need *at least* the higher number, but depending on use and particular analysis, possibly a lot more.